# Better python logic that prevent time out when comparing arrays in nested loops

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I was attempting to solve a programing challenge and the program i wrote solved the small test data correctly for this question. But When they run it against the larger datasets, my program timed out on some of the occasions . I am mostly a self taught programmer, if there is a better algorithm/implementation than my logic can you guys tell me.thanks.

**Question**

> Given an array of integers, a, return the maximum difference of any
>   pair of numbers such that the larger integer in the pair occurs at a
>   higher index (in the array) than the smaller integer. `Return -1` if you
>   cannot find a pair that satisfies this condition.

**My Python Function**

```
def maxDifference( a):
    diff=0
    find=0
    leng = len(a)
    for x in range(0,leng-1):
        for y in range(x+1,leng):
            if(a[y]-a[x]>=diff):
                  diff=a[y]-a[x]
                  find=1
    if find==1:
        return diff
    else:
        return -1
```

**Constraints:**

```
1 <= N <= 1,000,000
-1,000,000 <= a[i] <= 1,000,000 i belongs to [1,N]
```

**Sample Input:**

```
Array { 2,3,10,2,4,8,1}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
8
```

Comment: There is nested for loop so it is `O(n^2)` which won't get easily accepted on any online judge.

Comment: Here's a hint: You can find the biggest value before each index in linear time. You can find the smallest value after each index in linear time. Once you have those two lists, how could you avoid the inner loop, making your whole algorithm linear time instead of quadratic?

Comment: Meanwhile, you claim this code gives the right output, except for timing out against some large datasets… but it actually raises a `SyntaxError`, and if you fix that, it returns -1 for your sample input, not 8.

Comment: @anmol_uppal nested loops are something that was programmed into brain at school . so for every solution, brain kinda automatically throws it as the solution . think i need to learn bit more about ` big O notation`  and efficent algorithms

Comment: @abarnert it was a timed test and i couldn't copy the original code i wrote there, this is something i typed out from my brain later. let me try running it again. my main concern is i always follow nested loops at programs like this .
kinda unaware about what else are the solutions, let me rack up my brain on ur comment and try to think differently

Comment: Nested loops, where both loops go over all N values, inherently means quadratic time. When quadratic time is unavoidable (or just good enough for the problem domain), nested loops are often the most readable way to write things (although not always; sometimes `for x, y in product(…)` or using a NumPy array or similar is better…). But when there's a linear or log-linear solution, you probably have to go to a different structure.

Comment: Meanwhile, your fixed version still has the same SyntaxError; I didn't check whether you fixed anything else.

Comment: @abarnert :P i went for the small logical error. Now fixed the syntax error. thanks a lot of the helpful inputs :) .

Comment: nope, editted code still will only return -1 or 0 since `if find == 1` evaluates True whenever you reassign diff, and if you don't, diff is still 0

Comment: @Matthew: No, I think that's correct now. If he's reassigned `diff`, it'll `return diff`, which isn't necessarily (or even usually) 0. If he hasn't reassigned `diff`, it'll return `-1`, which is what he wants.

Comment: @Matthew: Rather than guessing, now that it runs, I just wrapped a 2-line driver around it and ran it, and it returns 8 with his sample input. So it's good.

Comment: The code was different, I apologize, the edit must not have kicked in (I was looking at `if find == 1: return -1`

Comment: @Matthew: Yeah, that was the original version I first asked about. (When someone says they edited and I can't see an edit, I always force-reload the page. I don't know how good SO's AJAX-y goodness is, but it's easier to just not trust it than to find out.:)

Comment: Can you give a link to that challenge? I'd like to try it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann it was a question asked to me for an interview, i think that challenge is not open to the public. but you can check out similar questions at https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms/warmup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your program takes too long is that your nested loop inherently means quadratic time.

The outer loop goes through `N-1` indices. The inner loop goes through a different number of indices each time, but the average is obviously `(N-1)/2` rounded up. So, the total number of times through the inner loop is `(N-1) * (N-1)/2`, which is `O(N^2)`. For the maximum `N=1000000`, that means 499999000001 iterations. That's going to take a long time.

The trick is to find a way to do this in *linear* time.

Here's one solution (as a vague description, rather than actual code, so someone can't just copy and paste it when they face the same test as you):

- Make a list of the smallest value before each index. Each one is just `min(smallest_values[-1], arr[i])`, and obviously you can do this in `N` steps.
- Make a list of the largest value after each index. The simplest way to do this is to reverse the list, do the exact same loop as above (but with `max` instead of `min`), then reverse again. (Reversing a list takes `N` steps, of course.)
- Now, for each element in the list, instead of comparing to every other element, you just have to compare to `smallest_values[i]` and `largest_values[i]`. Since you're only doing 2 comparisons for each of the `N` values, this takes `2N` time.

So, even being lazy and naive, that's a total of `N + 3N + 2N` steps, which is `O(N)`. If `N=1000000`, that means 6000000 steps, which is a whole lot faster than 499999000001.

You can obviously see how to remove the two reverses, and how to skip the first and last comparisons. If you're smart, you can see how to take the whole `largest_values` out of the equation entirely. Ultimately, I think you can get it down to `2N - 3` steps, or 1999997. But that's all just a small constant improvement; nowhere near as important as fixing the basic algorithmic problem. You'd probably get a bigger improvement than 3x (maybe 20x), for less work, by just running the naive code in PyPy instead of CPython, or by converting to NumPy—but you're not going to get the 83333x improvement in any way other than changing the algorithm.

Comment: thanks for taking time an answering all questions so clearly . i was thinking using some other data structure or program improvement was the solution . but understood that the big flow is my algorithms when approaching problems like this.
will take good note of all the points mentioned .

Answer (score 3):

Well... since you don't care for anything else than finding the highest number following the lowest number, provided that difference is the highest so far, there's no reason to do several passes or using `max()` over a slice of the array:

```
def f1(a):
    smallest = a[0]
    result = 0
    for b in a:
        if b < smallest: 
            smallest = b
        if b - smallest > result:
            result = b - smallest

    return result if result > 0 else -1
```

Thanks @Matthew for the testing code :)
This is very fast even on large sets:

```
The maximum difference is 99613 99613 99613
Time taken by Sojan's method: 0.0480000972748
Time taken by @Matthews's method: 0.0130000114441
Time taken by @GCord's method: 0.000999927520752
```

Comment: You need to return -1 for cases like `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` and not 0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a linear time solution. It keeps a track of the minimum value before each index of the list. These minimum values are stored in a list `min_lst`. Finally, the difference between corresponding elements of the original and the min list is calculated into another list of differences by zipping the two. The maximum value in this differences list should be the required answer.

```
def get_max_diff(lst):
    min_lst = []
    running_min = lst[0]
    for item in lst:
        if item < running_min:
            running_min = item
        min_lst.append(running_min)
    val = max(x-y for (x, y) in zip(lst, min_lst))
    if not val:
        return -1
    return val

>>> get_max_diff([5, 6, 2, 12, 8, 15])
13
>>> get_max_diff([2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 8, 1])
8
>>> get_max_diff([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
-1
```

Comment: I don't think `if not val` is what you want here. Maybe `if val <= 0`? (For example, consider `[8, 6, 4, 2]`.)

Comment: `val <= 0` can be used but there shouldn't be a case where val goes negative. So, the minimum it can go would be 0, like in the `[8, 6, 4, 2]` case you mentioned. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, I see, you're including each item itself in its own running min… yeah, I think that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figure since someone in the same problem can copy your code and run with that, I won't lose any sleep over them copying some more optimized code:

```
import time
import random

def max_difference1(a):
    # your function

def max_difference2(a):
    diff = 0

    for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
        curr_diff = max(a[i+1:]) - a[i]
        diff = max(curr_diff, diff)

    return diff if diff != 0 else -1

my_randoms = random.sample(range(100000), 1000)

t01 = time.time()
max_dif1 = max_difference1(my_randoms)
dt1 = time.time() - t01

t02 = time.time()
max_dif2 = max_difference2(my_randoms)
dt2 = time.time() - t02

print("The maximum difference is", max_dif1)
print("Time taken by your method:", dt1)
print("Time taken by my method:", dt2)
print("My method is", dt1/dt2, "times faster.")

The maximum difference is 99895
Time taken by your method: 0.5533690452575684
Time taken by my method: 0.08005285263061523
My method is 6.912546237558299 times faster.
```

Similar to what @abarnert said (who always snipes me on these things I swear), you don't want to loop over the list twice. You can exploit the fact that you know that your larger value has to be *in front of* the smaller one. You also can exploit the fact that you don't care for anything except the largest number, that is, in the list `[1,3,8,5,9]`, the maximum difference is 8 (9-1) and you don't care that 3, 8, and 5 are in there. Thus: `max(a[i+1:]) - a[i]` is the maximum difference for a given index.

Then you compare it with `diff`, and take the larger of the 2 with `max`, as calling default built-in python functions is somewhat faster than `if curr_diff > diff: diff = curr_diff` (or equivalent).

The `return` line is simply your (fixed) line in 1 line instead of 4

---

As you can see, in a sample of 1000, this method is ~6x faster (note: used python 3.4, but nothing here would break on python 2.x)

Answer (score 0):

I think the expected answer for

> 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 8, 5, 6, 10

will be 8 - 2 = 6 but instead [Saksham Varma code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30086122/1926476) will return 10 - 1 = 9.

Its `max(arr) - min(arr)`.

> Don't we have to reset the min value when there is a dip

. ie; `4 -> 2` will reset `current_smallest = 2` and continue diff the calculation with value '2'.

```
def f2(a):
    current_smallest = a[0]
    large_diff = 0
    for i in range(1, len(a)):

        # Identify the dip
        if a[i] < a[i-1]:
            current_smallest = a[i]

        if a[i] - current_smallest > large_diff:
            large_diff = a[i] - current_smallest
```